# How to prevent an opening listbox from overlapping elements below?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I have an add button which, when clicked on, creates a listbox containing 12 images. When an image is selected, it's highlighted. When I click the add button again, one more listbox is created and so on.

When I click on a listbox, the 12 images appear overlapping with the list below. How to avoid this overlapping?the code is in jsfiddle.net/b0xjhsLa/1/

Comment: Please give us a code snippet on jsfiddle

Comment: Or at least a screenshot

Comment: the code is in the http://jsfiddle.net/b0xjhsLa/